# how to run pyspark code from VScode Terminal using spark-submit cmd

Tags: python, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**I am trying to run the below code in vscode.**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def get_spark():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('IRIS_ETL').master('local[*]').getOrCreate()
    return spark
if __name__ =="__main__":
    spark = get_spark()
    iris_df = spark.read.csv('Iris.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
    iris_df.show()
```

I have tried the below approach: but getting errors as:

**spark-submit goodreads_booksETL.py**

output:

```
22/04/09 02:06:42 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anvesh\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Anvesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 285, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\Anvesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 125, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-C:/Users/Anvesh/1Spark/pyspark_projects/goodread_booksETL/goodreads_booksETL.py` not found.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```